# Crystal Reports - Compounding Total in For Loop - Unexpected Results

Tags: loops, for-loop, crystal-reports, integer

I've been coding for 15 years, know many languages, C#, C++, PHP, PAWN, SMALL, ETC ETC. Crystal syntax is probably the most inconsistent and nonsensical I have ever seen.

Anyhow, I am trying to do something simple here. I have a string formatted like this in my db:
"1-DESC, 2-OTHER, 5-MISC"

The '-' and ',' are delimeters for splitting the string up in my code. Anyhow I need to add 1+2+5 so that CR reports the total of those numbers. For some reason in following code I keep getting "30.00" when I should be getting 10. I can't make sense of how CR is doing this....

```
//create an array of strings by parsing a underscore-delimited string field
Stringvar Array strings := Split({Estim.User_Memo1}, ', ');

numbervar i; 
numbervar total = 0;
numbervar total2 = 0;
For i := 1 to count(strings) Do
( 
    If InStr(strings[i], '-') > 0 then 
    (
        Stringvar Array numdesc := Split(strings[i], '-');
        total2 := ToNumber(numdesc[1]);
        total := total + total2;
        //total := total + ToNumber(numdesc[1]);
    );
);

total;
```

My db input string being pulled is: "1-Cracked Head, 2-No Threads, 3-O/S Length, 4-U/S Length"

Excuse my redundant total variables. I have been trying to find workarounds for about an hour now.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Two small things: First, your variables should be declared as `Local`. Second, you are not initializing the `total` and `total2` variables with the assignment operator, you're using the equality operator. Still, when I try your code I get 10 no matter what. Are you absolutely sure of the value of `{Estim.User_Memo1}`? Have you gone through and printed each variable out in-turn as a sanity check? (You can use `Join()` to print arrays.)

Comment: Crystal syntax is inconsistent and nonsensical. Thats why I move this code inside a Command or a Stored Procedure, so I can use SQL to solve problem like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to assign the value the you need to use `:`.

Now tor retrive the number you can use `Val` function which will return numbers from a string in number format which will make arithematic operations easy.

Try this... Currently I don't have CR to test for syntax..but logic is something like this.

```
//create an array of strings by parsing a underscore-delimited string field
Stringvar Array strings := Split({Estim.User_Memo1}, ', ');

numbervar i; 
numbervar total:= 0;
numbervar total2:= 0;
For i := 1 to count(strings) Do
( 
//    If InStr(strings[i], '-') > 0 then 
  //  (
    //    Stringvar Array numdesc := Split(strings[i], '-');
      //  total2 := ToNumber(numdesc[1]);
        total := total + Val(strings[i]);
        //total := total + ToNumber(numdesc[1]);
  //  );
);

total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help everyone. Siva pretty much had it right. For some reason this works.

```
//create an array of strings by parsing a underscore-delimited string field
Stringvar Array strings := Split({Estim.User_Memo1}, ', ');

numbervar i:=1;
numbervar total:= 0;

For i := 1 to count(strings) Do
( 
If InStr(strings[i], '-') > 0 then 
(
    Stringvar Array numdesc := Split(strings[i], '-');
    total := total + Val(numdesc[1]);
);
);

total;
```